# Adding an ID to jQuery Mobile back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to add an ID to the auto-generated back button within jQuery Mobile so I can add my own styles to it.

I imagine it could be done by searching the DOM for anything with a data-rel of "back" and then appending an ID of, for example "back-button" to it however I can't seem to find the correct way to do this.

Could someone help me out please, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did `$("[data-rel='back']").prop("id", "back-button")` fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted something like this:

Live jsFiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dgJzP/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
    $('[data-rel="back"]').attr('id','some-back-button');
    $('#some-back-button').find('span .ui-btn-text').html('Baaaaack');
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! That worked when I removed #second. Thanks again